# MonoDevelop async/await compiler error

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mono, monodevelop

I am making simple app using MonoDevelop. I wanted to use async/await but it didn't work as I expected.

I have 2 async methods. Each returns Task. I'm trying to use one inside another.

```
    public static async Task<bool> Save ()
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(_pathToFile)) {
            return await  SerializeAsync (_current, fileStream);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<bool> SerializeAsync (object obj, Stream stream)
    {
        try {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew (
                () => { var settingsFormatter = new BinaryFormatter ();
                settingsFormatter.Serialize (stream, obj);          
            });
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Compiler throws next errors:

Error CS4008: Cannot await void method Relaxer.AppSettings.SerializeAsync(object, System.IO.Stream)'. Consider changing method return type to `Task' (CS4008) (Relaxer)

Error CS4001: Cannot await `System.Threading.Tasks.Task' expression (CS4001) (Relaxer)

I've done async methods before in VisualStudio + Resharper and never faced any issues like that. But MonoDevelop have poor autocompleting and refactoring so, maybe I missed up some points? Aslo while implementing SerializeAsync at first, it really returns void, but than I change its return type to Task before compiling.

If it matters: I use Kubuntu 14.04, MonoDevelop 4.0.12 and Mono 3.2.8

UPD: I've installed MonoDevelop 5.9.6 and tried to run my project. Got the same error. Then I copied all files to new solution and it was compiled without any troubles. Seems like it was some IDE bugs.

Comment: You already fixed the CS4008 error. What line of code is the CS4001 error talking about? On a side note, you should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`, but that wouldn't cause this compiler error.

Comment: Error CS4008 still occurs even after changing method return type. It looks like MonoDevelop has some cache and remembers that method was returning void. I know, that I can avoid those errors just using event-based methods (StartSerialize, that triggers SerializationCompleted event). But I prefer to fix async/await issues, if it is possible.

Comment: The latest is MonoDevelop 5.9.6, and do you have a solid reason to stick to the old? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives Mono version below 4.0 does not have full async/await support, so what you see should be the bugs and resolved already in new releases.

Comment: I used old IDE because of Muon-Discover package manager. I thougth there are the latest versions of apps. Hovewer, I've installed new version of MonoDevelop and updated my question. Thank yoo for help.

Comment: I thought mono didn't have async/await

Comment: @WarrenP It has. Now it has a lot of features. It supports almost everything from .Net 4.5 and c# 6:
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/